# X2Go: черный экран

Tags: ubuntu, xfce

Установил x2go server на Ubuntu 14, пытаюсь подключиться с удаленного пк (с винды), говорит мне ошибку:

> Host Key Validation fails

ну да ладно, почистил клиент x2go в appdata - все заработало, ровно до первого ребута сервера. После этого пытаюсь приконнектиться - сессия стартует (тип xfce) - но кроме блэкскрина ничего нет.

А вот выставляю тип сессии "локальный пк" - работает. Но локальный пк не вариант. С других пк пробовал - та же проблема, значит это что-то на сервере.

Так в чем может быть проблема? Куда копать?

Comment: *сессия стартует (тип xfce)* — как определили? / между прочим: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2242444&p=13224727#post13224727

Comment: xfce стоит в настройках сессии x2go

Comment: «стоит в настройках клиента» означает, что клиент попытается после старта *xserver-а* выполнить бинарник `xfce4` (не помню, как он правильно назыается). а на сервере такая программа имеется? ну и в общем: смотрите логи, обращайте внимание на то, что появляется в них при открытии *x-сессии*. очень похоже, что *xserver* у вас запускается, а вот программы после этого никакие не выполняются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

«xfce стоит в настройках клиента» означает, что клиент попытается после старта *xserver*-а выполнить бинарник `xfce4`. убедитесь, что на сервере такая программа имеется (установлен пакет *xfce4* с зависимостями).

ну и в общем: смотрите логи, обращайте внимание на то, что появляется в них при открытии *x-сессии*. очень похоже, что *xserver* у вас запускается, а вот программы после этого никакие не выполняются.